# Allow pod to delete/modify secrets

Tags: kubernetes

I want to create a cronjob which can refresh a secret value. Cronjob configuration:

```
# Create a file /opt/aws.yml and paste this content
#
# Apply using
#
# kubectl apply -f /opt/aws.yml
# kubectl -n default create sa secrets-manager

apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: refresh-aws-secret
  namespace: default
spec:
  schedule: "* */6 * * *" # Run each 6 hours
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
          serviceAccount: secrets-manager
          containers:
            - name: refresh-aws-secret
              image: bitnami/kubectl:latest
              imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
              env:
                - name: SECRET_NAME
                  value: regcred
              envFrom:
                - secretRef:
                    name: regcred
              command:
                - /bin/sh
                - -c
                - |-
                  kubectl delete secret --ignore-not-found ${SECRET_NAME}
                  kubectl create secret docker-registry ${SECRET_NAME} \
                  --docker-server=123456789.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com \
                  --docker-username=AWS \
                  --docker-password=$(aws ecr get-login-password)
```

I trigger it manually using the command:

```
kubectl create job --from=cronjob/refresh-aws-secret manual-001 -n default
```

But into newly created pod logs I get:

```
root@node1:/opt# kubectl logs manual-001-blqlq
Error from server (Forbidden): secrets "regcred" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:secrets-manager" cannot delete resource "secrets" in API group "" in the namespace "default"
/bin/sh: 5: aws: not found
error: either --from-file or the combination of --docker-username, --docker-password and --docker-server is required
root@node1:/opt# ^C
```

How I can properly configure permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bitnami/kubectl image inside which you are invoking a kubectl command using a cronjob. To achieve this, k8 internally uses a serviceAccount called secrets-manager, as you have defined it.

By default, a service account cant do much. You have to explicitly give a service account permissions, and in your case, from looking at your cronjob yaml and those logs, you need to give it permissions to create and delete a secret.

In this case, you can create Role and RoleBinding objects as shown below to allow your cronjob to execute kubectl commands (only those which allow it to create and delete a secret).

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: secrets-manager-role-example
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["secrets"]
  verbs: ["create", "delete"]
```

and

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: secrets-manager-rolebinding
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: secrets-manager
  apiGroup: ""
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: secrets-manager-role-example
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

PS: I have only tried to answer your question. Not looked at how you are managing to load environment variables, security implications etc. Also assuming you have RBAC enabled.

Comment: I don't know is RBAC enabled. I have just a basic kubernetes cluster installed with a Kubespray.

Comment: I applied the first part but for the second I get `The RoleBinding "secrets-manager-rolebinding" is invalid: subjects[0].apiGroup: Unsupported value: "rbac.authorization.k8s.io": supported values: ""
`

Comment: Use subjects.apiGroup: "". I’ll edit the answer to reflect this.